# switch user to site url

Tags: c#

I had to check about data retrieve from data base in DDL and if this data equal specific value user will redirect to specific site (URL) .I tried to make this with if statement but it did not work please anyone help me.

```
protected void IMGSite_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (DDLBrand.SelectedItem.Text="Sharp")
    {
             Response.Redirect("http://toshiba.elarabygroup.com/");

    }
    if (DDLBrand.SelectedItem.Text = "Seiko")
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://Seiko.elarabygroup.com/");

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it work not at all, or for some values only? Did you try break points in this method, e.g. on the first `if` statement and then on both `Redirect()` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DDLBrand.SelectedItem.Text = "Seiko"`

should be

`DDLBrand.SelectedItem.Text == "Seiko"`

Use two equal signs!  Same for other comparison (== "Sharp")

Edit:
To open in a new window try:

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://toshiba.elarabygroup.com/');</script>")
```

Comment: If that is the root cause the code above shouldn't compile in the first place and the error message will be "error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'".

Comment: it worked well but i want to open the link in new open not in same window

Comment: it didnot work
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://toshiba.elarabygroup.com/');</script>")

Comment: @Kareem your're missing http:// from your URL. Unless that was just stackoverflow removing it

I just tested that exact code in my program and it worked as you needed it too... are you running this through the debugger?  Is this code being called at all?